# display a bootstrap modal if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, bootstrap-modal

I have a test page that when a user clicks on a form button, a bootstrap modal appears and displays a yes/no message to the user. It seems to be working OK.

**However, I have been trying to change the code so that the bootstrap modal is displayed / triggered when the user checks a checkbox**, but I am having trouble understanding the code I have.

I am hoping someone can show me how to adapt my code so the checked checkbox triggers the modal display.

Here is the script code that I have

```
<script>
    // START: photograph remove modal code.
    $('a[photograph-remove-confirm]').click(function(ev) {

        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        if (!$('#photographRemoveConfirmModal').length) {

            $('body').append('<div id="photographRemoveConfirmModal" class="modal modal-confirm-small-width hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="miscConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><icon class="icon-remove"></icon></button><h4 class="modal-title" id="miscConfirmLabel">{% trans "Confirm" %} - {% trans "Remove" %} {% trans "Photograph" %}</h4></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">{% trans "Cancel" %}</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn-u btn-u-blue" id="photographRemoveConfirmOK">{% trans "Remove" %} {% trans "Photograph" %}</a></div></div>');

        }

        $('#photographRemoveConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('photograph-remove-confirm'));

        $('#photographRemoveConfirmOK').attr('href', href);

        $('#photographRemoveConfirmModal').modal({show: true});

        return false;

    });
    // FINISH: photograph remove modal code.
</script>
```

Here is the template button code that displays the modal when clicked:

```
<a href="#" id="test_button" class="btn" photograph-remove-confirm="Your Photograph will be removed only after you save the form!">{% trans "Test" %}</a>
```

Here is the template checkbox code that I want to use to trigger the modal:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id_remove_photograph" name="remove_photograph" class="checkbox_resize"  onchange="remove_photograph_change();"> Remove Photograph</input>
```

Here is the `onchange="remove_photograph_change"` function displayed in the checkbox above.

```
function remove_photograph_change() {

    if ($('#id_remove_photograph').is(':checked')) {

        // just some code

    }

}
```

Comment: follow this link http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals and use `$('#CheckBox').change();`

Comment: something like this?- http://jsfiddle.net/r0ao44e7/

Comment: Manoz, yes the same functionality - but after looking at your example code and trying to mimic the code I cannot get my code to operate the same way. Also I am using Bootrap version 2.

Comment: @user1261774, Can you implement a fiddle for this as I get to know what exactly not working?

Comment: Manoz, the fiddle is: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/juhbay2r/[link]. I think the issue is the `$('a[photograph-remove-confirm]').click(function(ev) {` of the modal code. Also, this is the 1st fiddle I have made - forgive me if it has errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the following changes will fix the issue you have.

Change your checkbox code to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id_remove_photograph" name="remove_photograph" class="checkbox_resize"  onchange="remove_photograph_change();" photograph-remove-confirm="Your Photograph will be removed only after you save the form!"> Remove Photograph</input>
```

Change your modal code to this:

```
    // START: photograph remove modal code.
    $('[photograph-remove-confirm]').click(function(ev) {

        if (!$('#photographRemoveConfirmModal').length) {

            $('body').append('<div id="photographRemoveConfirmModal" class="modal modal-confirm-small-width hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="miscConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><icon class="icon-remove"></icon></button><h4 class="modal-title" id="miscConfirmLabel">{% trans "Confirm" %} - {% trans "Remove" %} {% trans "Photograph" %}</h4></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">{% trans "Cancel" %}</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn-u btn-u-blue" id="photographRemoveConfirmOK">{% trans "Remove" %} {% trans "Photograph" %}</a></div></div>');

        }

        $('#photographRemoveConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('photograph-remove-confirm'));

        $('#photographRemoveConfirmModal').modal({show: true});

        return false;

    });
    // FINISH: photograph remove modal code.
```